# Show that an operator is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\{\alpha_{mn} ;m,n\geq 1\}$ be scalars satisfying

a- $M=\sup_n\sum_{m\geq 1}|\alpha_{mn}|<\infty $ , and

b- $\sup_n|\alpha_{mn}|<\infty$,

then $(Af)(n) = \sum_{m\geq 1}\alpha_{mn} f(m)$ defines a bounded operator $A$ on $\ell^1$ and $||A|| =M$

Comment: My apologies for such a late question, but I notice that some of the problems you have asked about are from Conway, which I am also working through.  I noticed that in Conway this problem is actually stated as $(Af)(m) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \alpha_{mn} f(n)$.  Was this a typo in the text? Because I have been trying to work through the problem and I'm not sure that $A$ as stated in Conway is necessarily bounded.

Answer (score 0):

By the Holder inequality, $\lVert Af \rVert \leq ||\sum_{m \geq 1} \alpha_{mn} ||_{\infty} ||f||_1$. By (a) and the definition of sup norm, $M=||\sum_{m \geq 1} \alpha_{mn} ||_{\infty}$.

Thus, $A$ is a bounded operator with operator norm at most $M$. Can you get the second part now?

Comment: I know $||Af||= \sum_n |\sum_m \alpha_{mn}f(m)|$, but I think you suppose  $||Af||= \sum_n |\sum_m \alpha_{mn}f(n)|$ and then use Holder inequality.  Is Changing the index correct?  I can use the adjoint of A to show $||A||=M$. Do you have another suggestion?